# How to import FBX file with texture map?

Tags: texturing

I download FBX file from Internet. There are fbx file and 1 folder contain texture map. When I import to Blender 2.8 they are not import with texture map. There are only model. How can I load texture map?

Comment: Have you tried `File > External Data > Find Missing Files`?

Comment: I did. Linked to folder path. But It not work.

Comment: Hmmm. Any chance this is a free model? If so, where can I download it? I don't want to ask you to upload the file in case it's something you paid for. What kind of texture map is it, .mtl?

Comment: Have you connected the texture map manually through nodes? Fbx contains material placements and UV maps, but not the actual materials. You have to connect them yourself, I believe. I wasn't reading before, I was thinking .obj

Comment: Could you test attached file:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuAcyL2kNiCPhvMy_sfLqzX20VEmkg?e=84kU9Y

Comment: Done. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So the answer is - included with your model are texture maps for 2 separate materials: one for the lid, and one for the back wall. I had to add a new material slot to one of them (maybe both, I can't remember) and hook up the texture maps through those, but the UV's are fine. There is both a reflection map and a glossy included as part of the texture pack, however, they are both the same image so I used one for a roughness map, and I'm not sure if the other one is supposed to be metallic, because I don't know what the final product is supposed to look like, so I omitted it.

Anyway, I connected the textures by the number in the name of their respected object (the only ones that apply to your materials end in 02 and 04), through the node setup in the image below. Note that the color space for the roughness and the normal maps is set to non-color - this is important. Have a look:

[image: MaterialsConnected]

I have a copy of the .blend file with everything connected. Let me know if you'd like to have it, and i'll send you the link.

Comment: Thank for your trying. But I'm not expert in CGI. I just intent to check FBX file then export it again to FBX then Import to Twinmotion. I think may be find other simple way.